# How to fix a circular dependency warning during 'rollup -c' in a React component library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, circular-dependency, rollup

I am creating a react-component-library using rollup to use in other projects. While running "rollup -c" the following warning is displayed

```
(!) Circular dependency
node_modules/util/util.js -> node_modules/util/node_modules/inherits/inherits.js -> node_modules/util/util.js
```

Other than this error my component library is working perfectly fine. I have tried to research it and there was only one relevant forum link I found. The user was facing the same error but he resolved it after rearranging his *plugins* array in rollup.config.js file. But I am using pure js instead of ts. Is there a chance this will break the frontend if we use it in production?

Here's a my rollup.config.js file -

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
// import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';


export default [
    {
        input: './src/index.js',
        external:["react","react-dom"],
        output: [
            {
                file: 'dist/index.js',
                format: 'cjs',
            },
            {
                file: 'dist/index.es.js',
                format: 'es',
                exports: 'named',
            }
        ],
        plugins: [
            postcss({
                // plugins: [],
                config: {
                    path: "./postcss.config.cjs",
                },
                extensions: [".css"],
                minimize: true,
                inject: {
                    insertAt: "top",
                },
            }),
            commonjs({
                include: 'node_modules/**',
                // namedExports: {
                //     'node_modules/react-is/index.js': ['isValidElementType']
                // }
            }),
            babel({
                exclude: 'node_modules/**',
                presets: ['@babel/preset-react',]
            }),
            external(),
            resolve({preferBuiltins:false}),
            // terser(),
            image(),
        ]
    }
];
```